# jquery UI: adjust width of div by slider change

Tags: jquery, slide

I use jquery [UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) and want onchange to adjust a width of a div:

```
            $('#slider').slider({
                value: [17],
                change: handleSliderChange
            });

        function handleSliderChange(){
        ...         
        }
```

here the html

```
    <div id="slider"></div>
<div id="vardiv" style="width:300px;height:20px;border:3px solid black"> Testing </div>
```

i want that by adjusting the slider the width of the div #vardiv should be adjusted proportionally.

I guess we have to calculate a bit and use some functions.

THX 4 your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the change function would only be called after releasing the mouse,
if you want to have realtime effect you can use the slide function
like this:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    value: 17,
    slide: handleSliderChange
});

function handleSliderChange(event, slider){
          $('#vardiv').css('width', slider.value + '%');
          $("#vardiv").text(slider.value + '%');   
}
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/WXfkK/1/

Answer (score 0):

To get this behavior I would write something like this, to get it short.

```
$("#slider").slider({
     change: function (event, ui) {
          $("#vardiv").css("width", ui.value + "%");
     }
});
```

This event will executes everytime the slider changes. Inside that event the vardiv element will get a new proportionally width to it´s parent.

Comment: you can get the value easier by accessing the  ui.value in your case.
no need to go get the whole slider object and then the value option :)

Comment: Of course, it is easier and more efficient. Thanks for your feedback